# MapStruct DTO property

Tags: java, mapping, dto, mapstruct

I need to have a property on my DTO like idEncrypted because they can pass me only encrypted, however, I need to map the decrypt id as I find on DB. I already have a decrypt method, but I don't know how to map it and ignore the idEncrypted.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyDTO {  

    private String idEncrypted;
  
    ...
    ...

}
```

I don't know where to do the conversion

```
idDecrypted = Long.parseLong(MyUtils.decrypt(idEncrypted));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own custom qualified method for doing the decryption.

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "idEncrypted", qualifiedByName = "decryptId")
    MyEntity map(MyDTO dto);

    @Named("decryptId")
    default Long decryptId(String id) {
        return id != null ? Long.parseLong(MyUtils.decrypt(id)) : null;
    }
}
```